# Make parent div spin, but without the children's content

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the text inside of the children absolutely positioned in the spinning div. So that the text is in the middle all the time. I didn't come across a solution, but I tried positioning it with an absolute and "removing" the transition in the child. Below there's a jsfiddle attached with the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/4r9kattx/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">This is child</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from{ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   }
  to{   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    border: 10px dashed red;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 12s linear infinite;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
}
```

Comment: probably easier to just animate the child in the opposite direction, effectively cancelling the effect.

Comment: Do they really have to be in a parent/child relation? Because you're doing something quite the opposite.

Comment: I would use a wrapper and set 2 divs, parent and child - independent of each other and overlay them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you shouldn't use parent/child relationship. Just let them be siblings inside a container (I kept the class names just for showing the difference):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent"></div>
    <div class="child">This is child</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from{ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   }
  to{   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    border: 10px dashed red;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 12s linear infinite;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
}
```

Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r9kattx/4/)